# running a docker container and trying to check the log of the container prints an error on console

Tags: docker

I have built the image into a container, why I try to print the log of the container I run in detach mode I get an error printout :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class EazyBankApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EazyBankApplication
```

Please how can I fix this, I have tried changing the run command to accommodate a directory path and it still persists.

```bash
FROM openjdk:17
RUN mkdir /eazyApp
COPY ./src/main/java/com/eazybank/ /eazyApp
WORKDIR /eazyApp
CMD java EazyBankApplication
```

Comment: try to run `java EazyBankApplication` manually from inside the container, to see what happens with: `docker run -ti eazy-bank:1.0 bash`. Then you will be able to run shell commands in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you're `COPY`ing only a single source directory into the image.  When the container tries to execute the `CMD java EazyBankApplication`, the corresponding `.class` file doesn't exist.

Many SO Java questions address this by compiling the application on the host, and then `COPY` the built jar file (but not any of its source) into the image.

```bash
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /eazyApp
COPY target/eazybankapplication-0.0.1.jar ./
CMD java -jar eazybankapplication-0.0.1.jar
```

If you want to build the application inside Docker, then you need to invoke the build tool somehow.  A typical approach is to `COPY` the entire application tree into the image, excluding parts of it via a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

```bash
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /eazyApp

# Copy in the entire source tree
# (.dockerignore file excludes host's build/)
COPY ./ ./

# Build the application
RUN ./gradlew build

# Run it
CMD java -jar build/libs/eazybankapplication-0.0.1.jar
```

(You could combine the two approaches with a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to get a final image without the source code, and possible with only the JRE for a smaller image.)

You probably need a build system like Gradle or Maven in practice, but if you only have the source files, you can still directly use `javac`.

```bash
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /eazyApp
COPY ./src/ ./src/
RUN mkdir class
ENV CLASSPATH=/eazyApp/class
RUN find src -name '*.java' -print > files.txt \
 && javac -dclass @files.txt \
 && rm files.txt
CMD java com.eazybank.EazyBankApplication
```

Comment: This procedure worked that particular error out, I had to build an executable jar file on maven to do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your copy command does not copy the files in the directory, use

```
COPY ./src/main/java/com/eazybank/* /eazyApp
```

Also you don't need mkdir command, copy command will create the directory.